# Can any symplectomorphism (1 Definition of canonical transformation) be represented by the flow of a vectorfield?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, vector-fields, flow, phase-space

For this question I will use the definition that a canonical transformation is a map $T(q,p)$ from the phase space onto itself, which leaves the symplectic 2-form invariant (which is the definition of a symplectomorphism). 
I know that if the topology of the phase space is allright (which means there are no holes, and any closed path can be drawn to a point), then any vectorfield $V(q,p)$, with  a flow $F(q, p, \alpha)$ with $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \alpha} = V(q,p)$ and $F(q,p, 0) = (q, p)$ can be generated by a function on the phase space.

**What I'd like to know now is wether every symplectomorphism (not a flow, just a symplectomorphism) $T(q,p)$ can be seen as a flow, that means, for every T, I find a flow $F$ so that $T(q,p) = F(q, p, \alpha)$ for a certain value of $ \alpha $.**

For example, take the symplectomorphism $T(q, p) = (p, -q)$.  I could represent this symplectomorpohism with the Flow 
$$
F(q, p, \alpha) = (cos(\alpha) q + sin (\alpha) p , -sin(\alpha) q + cos (\alpha) p) 
$$
Then it would hold that $F(q, p, \frac{\pi}{2}) = T(q, p)$. 
Is that true in general? do I find such a flow for any symplectomorphism I want to look at?

I couldn't think of a counter example, but I don't know how to show it either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OP asks good questions.

First of all, let us mention that there is a bijective correspondence between 1-parameter [symplectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism) [flows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)) and parameter-independent$^1$ [symplectic vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_field). The latter are by definition vector fields $X\in \Gamma(TM)$ that preserve the symplectic 2-form ${\cal L}_X\omega=0$.

OP is essentially asking the following (some of it in previous versions of the question).

> 1. Is the symplectomorphism group path-connected?

*Answer:* Not necessarily, there could be topological obstructions.

*2D counterexample:* Let the phase space $M=\mathbb{S}^2$ be the 2-sphere equipped with the standard symplectic 2-form $\omega$. The second [homotopy group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group) $\pi_2(\mathbb{S}^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is non-trivial. $\Box$

> 2. Is any symplectomorphism the 1-time of a 1-parameter symplectic flow, i.e. is it the exponential $\exp(X)$ of a symplectic vector field $X$?

*Answer:* Not necessarily, there could be topological obstructions.

*Conjectured 2D counterexample:* Consider the phase space $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ with the symplectic 2-form $\omega =\mathrm{d}p\wedge \mathrm{d}q$. Consider the canonical transformation

$$ \begin{bmatrix} Q \cr P \end{bmatrix}
~=~ A\begin{bmatrix} q \cr p \end{bmatrix}, \qquad 
A~:=~\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1\cr 3 & -2  \end{bmatrix}~\in~Sp(2,\mathbb{R})~=~SL(2,\mathbb{R}). $$

We claim that this symplectomorphism can not be generated by a symplectic flow. A tell-tale fact is that the matrix $A$ has no square root.

Another clue is that this symplectomorphism only has the origin as a fixed point. This means that a symplectic vector field $X$ (for a flow, if it exists) can at most vanish at the origin.

Interestingly, one can write this symplectomorphism as a [canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) with a [type-2 generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function)

$$F_2(q,P)~=~-\frac{1}{2}qP +\frac{3}{4}q^2 - \frac{1}{4}P^2. $$

However we conjecture that a 1-parameter deformation from the identity $F_2(q,P)=qP$ must always go through a singular point.

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1051255/11127) related Math.SE post. $\Box$

> 3. Is any symplectic vector field $X\in \Gamma(TM)$ a [Hamiltonian vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field)?

*Answer:* Not necessarily, there could be topological obstructions. In fact, this is measured by the first [Poisson cohomology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poisson+cohomology) group.

*2D counterexample:* Consider the phase space $M=\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}$ with the symplectic 2-form $\omega =\mathrm{d}p\wedge \mathrm{d}q$. One may check that the vector field
$$X=\frac{q}{q^2+p^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial q} +\frac{p}{q^2+p^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial p} $$
is symplectic but it is *not* a Hamiltonian vector field. The problem is that the candidate ${\rm arg}(q+ip)$ for the Hamiltonian generator is multi-valued, and hence not globally well-defined.

See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81754/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53625/2451) related Phys.SE posts. $\Box$

--

$^1$ Note that there exists a notion of [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)#Time-dependent_ordinary_differential_equations) corresponding to a *parameter-dependent* vector field. We shall not consider this in this answer. Such flows are used in e.g. [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/9335/13917) related MO.SE post.

Comment: Qmechanic gives good answers.

Comment: Notes for later: (The following is only further speculations/conjectures lacking proofs.) Consider symplectomorphisms of the form $$ Q~:=~ f(q),\qquad  P ~:=~p/f^{\prime}(q),$$ on the cotangent bundle $M=T^{\ast}\mathbb{S}^1$with the symplectic 2-form $\omega =\mathrm{d}p\wedge \mathrm{d}q$. Then the exponential map $\exp:{\rm Vect}(M,\omega)\to {\rm Symp}(M,\omega)$ is not even locally surjective arbitrarily close to the identity.

Comment: Canonical transformations corresponding to parity transformations in odd spacial dimensions seem to provide rather trivial counterexamples.

Comment: The post you referred to about parameter dependent flows  just makes statements on a 2 dimensional phase space. If you consider parameter dependent flows in your answer, would the answer still be no for the question wether one could always find a parameter dependent flow that describes a given canonical transformation?

Comment: A flow corresponding to a parameter-dependent vector field is still a path-connected family of symplectomorphisms. Counterexample 1 shows that 2 symplectomorphisms are not necessarily path-connected.

Comment: @Dexter Kim: If we identity $z=q+ip$, then a parity transformation $Q=-q$ can be reached via OP's rotation flow $Z(z,\alpha)=e^{i\alpha}z$ with $\alpha=\pi$.