# Is an integrator with unit Jacobian determinant sympletic?

Tags: differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, computational-physics, hamiltonian, integration

Consider a numerical integrator $\phi(q, p)$ having $|\text{det } \phi'| = 1$. Can we say the integrator is sympletic, that is that
$$
\phi'^\top J^{-1} \phi' = J^{-1}
$$
where
$$
J^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & I \\
    -I & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

> In other words, if an integrator has absolute determinant Jacobian equal to $1$ can we say it is sympletic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not all unimodular/divergencefree flows in phase space are symplectic. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81754/2451) related Phys.SE post.