# Measure-preserving vs. non-dissipative vs. Hamiltonian systems

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, vector-fields, phase-space, dissipation, volume

Are measure-preserving systems always non-dissipative? Phase space volume is preserved in both, according to Liouville's theorem. But are there any differences?

Are measure-preserving and [non-dissipative systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_system) necessarily Hamiltonian systems, and vice versa?

Also, I have seen a claim that measure-preserving systems are a special case of conservative systems. What are the additional conditions to make a conservative system a measure-preserving one.

Comment: By measure you mean the phase space volume measure?

Comment: Related: [Does Hamilton Mechanics give a general phase-space conserving flux?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81754/2451)